# Understanding cookies (using jquery cookie plugin.)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am working on a project that has a Flash video that autoplays once it loads on the page. My client would like it only to autoplay the first time someone visits the page. Consequent visits (in the same session) would load the video, but keep it paused.

The Flash video has a JS function that I can call to pause or play the video. So my thought was to set a cookie once the user visits the page and have it trigger the callback on consequent visits.

```
//wait until everything has loaded
$(window).load(function(){

    //set a cookie 
    $.cookie('welcome_cookie', 'welcome');

    //check for the cookie and call the pause function
    if($.cookie('welcome_cookie')){
        controlPlayback('pause');
    }
});
```

This works, but it pauses the video on the very first time... How do I make it so that the playback function is triggered only on return to this page?

Comment: Just invert the order.
First test and then add the cookie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just switch order to set the cookie after the first check;

```
//wait until everything has loaded
$(window).load(function(){

    //check for the cookie and call the pause function
    if($.cookie('welcome_cookie')){
        controlPlayback('pause');
    }

    //set a cookie 
    $.cookie('welcome_cookie', 'welcome');
});
```

You probably don´t have to set the cookie on every page load so why not just set the cookie if it´s not set;

```
//check for the cookie and call the pause function
if($.cookie('welcome_cookie')){
    //pause video player
    controlPlayback('pause');
} else {
  //set a cookie 
  $.cookie('welcome_cookie', 'welcome');
}
```

Comment: The reason I have the $(window).load) is so that I know the flash player has loaded before attempting to call the playback function. Otherwise I get an undefined Method error.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a cookie for this, cookie gets transmitted to and from server at every request and response respectively. So you are sending back and forth data that you really don't need at server. What you really need is localstorage.

```
$(window).load(function(){

    //If not first visit then pause
    if(localStorage['not_first_visit']){
        controlPlayback('pause');
    }

    //Set  
    localStorage('not_first_visit')=true;
});
```

Comment: what is the browser support for localStorage? As long as it will work with IE7+ I would be willing to try this approach.

Comment: IE7+ definitely supports localStorage.

Comment: Just a sec, according to [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/html5.html) IE7 doesn't support localStorage.

Comment: ah well... I'll keep this in mind for future projects where IE7 support is not required. :) Thanks for the insights!